# Launch selenium webdriver test from terminal in linux

Tags: java, linux, selenium, webdriver, classpath

I wrote a simple regression test for a website with a little GUI to launch the test. Works fine in eclipse but for some reason it will stall after pressing the launch button on the GUI when I try to run it from the terminal. The web driver will launch firefox but the page stays blank when its supposed to go to the URL of the site I'm testing. I believe this has to do with error in configuring the classpath, I have the following in a shell script

```
javac -classpath ":ojdbc6.jar:selenium-server-2.33.0.jar:selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar" Test.java
java -classpath ":ojdbc6.jar:selenium-server-2.33.0.jar:selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar" Test
```

Why does it stall and how to fix it?

Comment: I occasionaly had some problems with firefox too. Did you try the Chrome webdriver as a test? Had much better experiences with this.

Comment: Chrome isn't an option, unfortunately. I'm just wondering why it'll work when I launch it in eclipse but not when I compile it and run it through the terminal

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Junit ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) to run my tests. It will run my tests and print a nice looking html report at the other end for clear results.

Comment: Are you on a Linux environment?

Comment: Yep! You define a simple target in the ant build.xml file then call that from the command line. I don't even know the first thing about ant, and managed to get it going :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Ant or Maven build tool with Junit or TestNG framework as both framework has capability of running test from terminal and generating nice html formated report. Here is a sample project with ant build script you can get from my [github](https://github.com/reazp/Medialets) account.